# Would a future Dyson sphere or swarm around our Sun actually be beneficial to people on Earth?

Tags: the-sun, earth, artificial-satellite, seti

A Dyson sphere or swarm's function is to harvests most of a star's energy, correct?

However, a future Dyson sphere around *our Sun* would also block the Sun's rays from reaching Earth. Wouldn't it freeze the people on Earth to death and ruin the bio-sphere?

Or is there some way around that?

Comment: This probably is better for [WorldBuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There are [numerous Dyson sphere questions](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Dyson+sphere).

Comment: I have mixed thoughts on this - a lot of the Dyson sphere questions we've had previously have been about observations which might include Dyson spheres, and they do play a role in SETI. On the other hand, they're artificial constructs, rather than natural astronomical objects, so I could see this either way. Given that it's not about world building, though, I'm not inclined to migrate it there.

Comment: @HDE226868 It seems to me that the OP want's to know if people on our Earth won't freeze themselves after they build a Dyson sphere around our Sun, not about spotting existing Dyson spheres . So the OP's question is probably not about Astronomy. I think Space SE (which does have questions about future engineering projects in space) might be a good home, and I'm sure there will end up being sources that can be cited in answers to this, possibly even from [Sir Dyson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeman_Dyson).

Comment: Maybe a moderator will find this and decide

Comment: Why there are so recurrent questions on Dyson spheres in SE? They should really appear on World Building only, except if used as ideal situation for physical calculation.

Comment: A Dyson sphere with a window along the ecliptic would probably do the trick

Comment: No one said the Dyson sphere has to be inside Earth's orbit.  Also note before sending it [worldbuilding.se] that there are multiple Q&As on Dyson spheres and **Dyson swarms** (spheres are not stable and swarms are more rational) there.  In addition if they can build something as insanely vast as a Dyson sphere or swarm, the least of Earth's problems would be energy as they'd now have access to the entire solar output not just a minute fraction of it.

Comment: @StephenG what do you mean by "inside earth's orbit"

Comment: Your question asks about blocking the Sun from Earth.  That could only happen if it orbits inside the Earth's orbit - i.e. closer to the Sun than Earth.

Comment: @StephenG Oh now I understand what you mean, but if the sphere were outside earth's orbit would it not get hit by asteroids and other stuff?

Comment: Why would it not get hit by asteroids or comets inside Earth's orbit ?  They don't keep to lanes. :-)  Also the amount of material required to *build* a Dyson sphere is *staggeringly* large.  It's unlikely there would be any asteroids around.

Comment: @CiurkitboyN  If the future civilization is advanced enough to build a Dyson shellor Dyson Sphere, it will provide many millions of times as much living space as Earth does, so they might think it would be a good idea to disassemble Earth for building materials.  Anyway, a civilization that could built a Dyson sphere or a Dyson Shell would have no trouble building a giant satellite that orbited the Earth and shined enough light on it to keep Earth habitable.  A Dyson shell or sphere would be many millions of times harder to construct than an artificial sun satellitetoilluminate Earth.

Comment: It takes a *lot* of matter to build a Dyson shell, and Earth has over half of the terrestrial matter in the inner Solar System (i.e., all the stuff outside the Sun, upto & including the main asteroid belt). If you ground up all that stuff (~11.888E24 kg) & built a shell at 57.9E6 km (Mercury's mean orbital radius) with the density of granite (~2750 kg/m³), it'd be around 10 cm thick. Here's the relevant Google Calculator string: `(11.888E24 kg)/(4*pi*(57.9E6 km)^2*(2750 kg/m^3))` if you want to play with the numbers.